# Fetching multiple objects with same prefix from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have multiple folders in an s3 bucket and each folder contains some `.txt` files. Now I want to fetch just 10 `.txt` files from a given folder using javascript API.
For eg: the path is something like this

```
s3bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3/id
```

Now folder `id` is the one containing multiple .txt files. There are multiple `id` folders inside folder3. I want to pass `id` and get 10 s3 objects which have `id` as prefix. Is this possible using listObjectsV2? How do I limit the response to just 10 objects.

```
                                              ____obj1.txt
                                 ______id1----|____obj2.txt
                                 |            _____obj3.txt
                                 |_____ id2---|____obj4.txt
s3bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3-|            ____obj5.txt
                                 |_____ id3---|____obj6.txt
```

So if I pass

```
var params= {Bucket:"s3bucket",Key:"folder1/folder2/folder3/id1"}
```

I should get `obj1.txt` and `obj2.txt` in response.

Answer (score 2):

Which [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) method are you using? I suggest to use [`listObjectsV2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property) to achieve your goal. A possible call might look as the following

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const { Contents } = await s3.listObjectsV2({
    Bucket: 's3bucket',
    Prefix: 'folder1/folder2/folder3/id1',
    MaxKeys: 10
}).promise();
```

To get the object values you need to call [`getObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) on each `Key`.

```
const responses = await Promise.all((Contents || []).map(({ Key }) => (
    s3.getObject({
        Bucket: 's3bucket',
        Key
    }).promise()
)));
```

Comment: how can I get the object values from the object keys returned returned in the reponse?

Comment: could you explain the second part a bit?